# How can I stream audio from Android to Ubuntu over USB

Tags: 14.04, usb, sound, pulseaudio, android

Android supports [using the USB port as an audio output](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/custom.html) so I wanted to connect it to my USB port and have a new audio input on Ubuntu.

I know this can be done using bluetooth or with a multimedia server over wifi, but I wanted to do it using the USB port. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you can interpreter the audio on the USB without any fancy software. As such gathering audio input from a USB should be the same as gathering audio from any generic USB audio source, such as a mic.

Here is a link that might be useful as a launchpad.
http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/USB_mic_on_Linux

Comment: My phone is detected as a storage unit so I don't think I can do what you propose...